# Updating through put getting exception : Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following two models

```
class modelJob(models.Model):
    category            = models.ForeignKey(modelJobCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    description         = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
```

and this model

```
class modelJobCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    other = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False , blank=True , null=True)
```

These are my two serializers

```
class Serializer_Update_Job_Serializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
        category = Serializer_Create_List_JobCategory
        fields = [
            'category',
            'description',
        ]

class Serializer_Create_List_JobCategory(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = modelJobCategory
        fields = [
            'name',
            'other',
        ]
```

Now I am attempting to update through PUT at the url with a lookup field `pk`
however I am getting the exception

```
{
  "category": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."
  ]
}
```

This is what my view looks like

```
class UpdateJob_RetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = modelJob.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializer_Update_Job_Serializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = self.queryset
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Any idea why I am getting this error ?

This is the body of my PUT

```
{
    "description": "foobar",

    "category" : {
        "name" : "labor",
        "other" : "blah"
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your PUT request look like? What data are you sending?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put that in the post. Let me update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to create an 'update' method on your job serializer. See the documentation here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers. By default a serializer doesn't understand how to save a nested serializer.

Your update method might look like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data, id):
    # Perform any updates to the instance you want to do
    # using the validated_data, then save the category
    instance.category = modelJobCategory.objects.get_or_create(
        name=validated_data['category']['name']
    )
```

A simpler, perhaps nicer approach would be to use a writable SlugRelatedField. So changing your update job serializer to have a category field that looks like:

```
category = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name')
```

This way when you are saving the job with it's category you just send the name of the category. Not the whole category object.

If you want to understand what the error means. Django rest framework is trying to figure out which category to save on your job. But to do that it would use a primary key. The database id. An integer. What you're sending in your PUT request is the category dict, with name and description. But no database id. And django has no idea how to turn that dictionary object into a category that it can save to the database for you.

Comment: if I add the update method it never gets called instead I get the error `TypeError at /api/job/upd/3/
update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

Comment: Ah, okay, you're getting close. You need to change the signature of the method to either have a keyword argument of id. Like `def update(instance, validated_data, id=None):` or `def update(instance, validated_data, **kwargs):`.